# Can't change link strength when using forceX/Y

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gdXprR?editors=1010

I have the ability to change the strength of the links by pressing the buttons in the UI which changes the following :

```
force.force('link').strength(+linkStrength);
force.alpha(1).restart();
```

Now when I press the buttons in the UI, nothing effects the network. However, when I change the force from this:

```
.force('x', d3v5.forceX(width / 2))
.force('y', d3v5.forceY(height / 2));
```

To this :

```
.force('center', d3v5.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
```

Here is the codePen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QVQwRp?editors=1010

Lowering the strength works.

My questions are why? And how would I make use of the original setup, i.e. setting the `forceX` and `forceY` and be able to change the link strength, so that the nodes spread out more on screen?

Thanks

Comment: think I have it, decreasing the strength when setting the forceX/Y moves the nodes closer to the original positions of the force network. Decreasing the strength when setting the forceCenter, moves the nodes out from the center point. I'll probably have to adjust the actual link length to solve the problem i have

Comment: `forceX`, `forceY` are forces and `forceCenter` is about the **center of gravity**

Comment: @rioV8 `forceCenter` is a force, just like `forceX` and `forceY`.

Comment: @thatOneGuy you are correct, there must be a compromise between the `strength` of those forces (have in mind that, unlike positioning, centering has no strength). After all, you cannot say *"hey, you go to point A and you go to point B"* and *"hey, the distance between you too must to be twice the distance from A to B"* at the same time!